# Identify if string can be converted into int array

Tags: java, regex

I have a converter that will convert an array of int into a String.

```
**EDIT** [1, 2, -45, 678] -> "1 2 -45 678";
[1] -> "1"
```

Into this converter, I have a `supportFromString` method to identify if the string can be converted back into an array.

I though of using regex to do so, but I can't find a good match.
I tried `"\\d+\\s"` and `"[\\d+]\\s"` but `s.matches(pattern)` returns false.

Any suggestion? If one non-numeric character is found, it's not valid.

**EDIT**
Here is the toString method of the converter

```
@Override
public String toString(Object o, ConverterContext converterContext) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (Integer integer : ((Integer[]) o)) {
        if (builder.toString().length() > 0) {
            builder.append(" ");
        }

        builder.append(integer);
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java

Comment: What happened when you tried those regexes? A good question explains what you've tried *and why it didn't work*.

Comment: You could match the string with the following regex: `[0-9 ]+` and compare it to the original string to see if they are equal.

Comment: s.matches(_pattern_) returns false

Comment: @tenub, this will match only single digits followed by a space, but I could get any valid integer into my array.

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches only? I.e. must there be only one space between all numbers and no trailing space at the end?

Comment: @P.Lalonde Did you notice that the `converterContext` variable is never used in the `toString` method...

Comment: @Alex, yes, this is because my converter is registered into a third party library, I need to match their Interface, but this object contains nothing usefull for my converter to convert values.

Comment: @Lalonde, tenub's regex matches any combination of at least one number or space. It should work for the given string. Are you trying to match something more specific?

Comment: @mdl, I was not clear into the example, let me edit my post, integers can also be negative.

Comment: @P.Lalonde The pattern `\\d+\\s+` doesn't match because the last number is not followed by a blank character (space). See this answser:http://stackoverflow.com/a/20977684/363573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
String pattern = "(-?\\d+\\s*)+";
String test = "1 -5 2 45 678";

System.out.println(test.matches(pattern));
```

**Output**

> True

If you want to find the digits, use this pattern alone: `-?\\d+\\s*`.

Comment: Yes, this would work, but ints can also be negative.

Comment: @P.Lalonde Check my update. As long as there is no character between minus and the integer in your use case, the update is ok.

Comment: Yes, and it's simpler than the other one

Answer (score 2):

I would test the string against the following regex:

`[^\d ]`

If you get any results it means you have something else other than a digit (\d) or a space

Answer (score 1):

```
static Pattern validPattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\-{0,1}\\d+\\s)*(\\-){0,1}\\d+$");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    isStringValid("1 2 3 4 5");
    isStringValid("1 26 35 44 53");
    isStringValid("1 2a 3s 4 5");
    isStringValid("1234");
    isStringValid("1");
    isStringValid("1 ");
    isStringValid("a b c");
    isStringValid("1 b c");
    isStringValid("1 1 2 33333");
    isStringValid("-1 1 2 33333");
    isStringValid("1 1 2 -33333");
    isStringValid("1 1 2 ----33333");
    isStringValid("---1 1 2 -33333");
}

public static boolean isStringValid(String s){
    s = s.trim();
    boolean b = validPattern.matcher(s).find();

    if (b){
        System.out.printf("%s: is valid.\n", s);
    }else{
        System.out.printf("%s: is NOT valid.\n", s);
    }

    return(b);
}
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 4 5: is valid.
1 26 35 44 53: is valid.
1 2a 3s 4 5: is NOT valid.
1234: is valid.
1: is valid.
1: is valid.
a b c: is NOT valid.
1 b c: is NOT valid.
1 1 2 33333: is valid.
-1 1 2 33333: is valid.    
1 1 2 -33333: is valid.
1 1 2 ----33333: is NOT valid.
---1 1 2 -33333: is NOT valid.
```

Comment: Yes, this would work, but ints can also be negative.

Comment: Correct. I fixed the regex to also allow negative values.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you can use to test if the string is a number optionally followed by other numbers separated by one or more spaces:

```
"(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)(\\s+(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*))*"
```

EDIT: Included negative integers and excluded leading zeros.

Comment: Yes, this would work, but ints can also be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Here my take, which handles negative numbers.

```
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import  java.util.Arrays;
/**
   <P>java IntArrayToStringToIntArray</P>
 **/
public class IntArrayToStringToIntArray  {
   private static final Pattern pDigits = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {

      String sArray = Arrays.toString(new int[]{1, 2, -45, 678});
         System.out.println("---The array: " + sArray);
         System.out.println(isSafeToConvertToStringedArrayToIntArray(sArray));
         int[] ai = getIntArrayFromToStringedArray(sArray);
         for(int i : ai)  {
            System.out.println(i);
         }
         System.out.println();

      sArray = Arrays.toString(new int[]{1});
         System.out.println("---The array: " + sArray);
         System.out.println(isSafeToConvertToStringedArrayToIntArray(sArray));
         ai = getIntArrayFromToStringedArray(sArray);
         for(int i : ai)  {
            System.out.println(i);
         }
         System.out.println();

      sArray = "bogus";
         System.out.println("---The array: " + sArray);
         System.out.println(isSafeToConvertToStringedArrayToIntArray(sArray));
   }


   //Assumes the string is formatted as if by Arrays.toString(int[])
   public static final boolean isSafeToConvertToStringedArrayToIntArray(String s_ofInts)  {
      //Eliminate the surrounding square brackets
      s_ofInts = s_ofInts.substring(1, s_ofInts.length() - 1);
      String[] as = s_ofInts.split(", ");

      for(String s : as)  {
         Matcher m = pDigits.matcher(s);
         if(!m.matches())  {
            return  false;
         }
      }

      return  true;
   }


   //Assumes the string is formatted as if by Arrays.toString(int[])
   public static final int[] getIntArrayFromToStringedArray(String s_ofInts)  {
      //Eliminate the surrounding square brackets
      s_ofInts = s_ofInts.substring(1, s_ofInts.length() - 1);

      String[] as = s_ofInts.split(", ");

      int[] ai = new int[as.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < as.length; i++)  {
         String s = as[i];
         Matcher m = pDigits.matcher(s);
         if(m.matches())  {
            ai[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
         }  else  {
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("getIntArrayFromToStringedArray: Element " + i + " in s_ofInts is not an int: \"" + s + "\".");
         }
      }
      return  ai;
   }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a regex.

Comment: The point of your question is to create a `supportFromString` function. A regex is one part of the picture. I created your function exactly as specified (despite the different name), using your exact demo-data. And there *IS* a regex in there. A downvote for all this work really sucks.

Answer (score -1):

You could read the entire input line from scanner, then split the line by,then you have a String[], parse each number into int[] with index one to one matching(assuming valid input and no NumberFormatExceptions)like
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] numberStrs = line.split(",");
int[] numbers = new int[numberStrs.length];
for(int i = 0;i < numberStrs.length;i++)
{
numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberStrs[i]);
}

Comment: Performance wise, I am not sure this is the best solution, I really think regex should be the best thing to do.

Comment: Why is your answer littered with `<br/>`? Just start a new line in the editor if you want a new line. And place your code in a code block. See the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info.

Comment: Why in the world are you downvoting answers you don't agree with, or happen to be a different flavor than you might choose? Your question does not specify "performance must be optimal".

Comment: Clearly the intent here is to help you. Downvoting does not make us want to help.